# Firebase query for value inside an array that is in a document?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, backend

I am new to ReactJS and Firebase and currently, I am trying to update some fields in my Firebase Firestore but I am not sure how to. I am using ReactJS to create this web application. I have an array inside a document (tied to the userid which Firebase automatically creates) and this array consists of "maps" (from what I see based on the console) with keys and values.

For example, I am trying to access all the maps with a "symbol" key equal to "MSFT". How can I make such a query and update that particular map inside the array?
[image]

Comment: can you share your src i m experimenting with arrays myself maybe i can do it